# Jquery Slider not working on homepage

Tags: jquery, html, css, magento-go

I am trying to display a slider on magentogo store but somehow despite copying all code from the demo example of slider along with css the slider is not working. The css is set to display none as this is how slider works. But Jquery is not calling the slider code in loop.js file. I am really stuck here so please help.

I am using  loopedslider: 
[github.com/mcarmen/loopedSlider#markup](http://github.com/mcarmen/loopedSlider#markup)

and here is the website:
https://magoopaddleboards.gostorego.com/#

Regards Ahmar

Answer (score 0):

You have a display none for the class .slides div. It doesn't look like it's in a css file... It might be done through a plugin.

Screenshot of this:

[image]

Comment: It was a slight error and I have managed to make the image appear but slider is still not working. Can you please take a look and check what is the problem